# how to get number of micro seconds in a day

Tags: java

I want to get the number of micro seconds in a day

so I tried as per below

```
long microDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000;
```

for which I am expecting value as `86400000000` but when I print it

```
System.out.println(microDay);
```

The value is `500654080`

After spending 3 hours and breaking my head to know the reason,final I found that java think 24,60 and 1000 as int values and `int*int =int` but the maximum value of int is 2147483647 so it cant store 86400000000 and hence it the output is 500654080 (but I am not sure)

In the second case I wanted to calculate miliseconds in a day and the formula goes like this

```
long miliDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
System.out.println(miliDay );
```

**output** 86400000

now when I did

```
System.out.println(microDay/ miliDay);
```

**output** 5

but when I tried this in a calculator `500654080/86400000= 5.794607407407407`
why there is different in result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're performing 32-bit integer arithmetic, as every operand in `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000` is an `int`... but the result is bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, so it's overflowing (just as you suspected). (This is actually happening at compile-time in this case, because it's a compile-time constant, but the effect is the same as if it happened at execution time.)

Effectively, each operation is truncated to 32 bits. As it happens, only the final multiplication by 1000 takes the result over 2<sup>31</sup> - 86400000 is fine.

86400000000 in binary is:

```
1010000011101110101110110000000000000
    ^
    \- Bit 33
```

So after overflow, we just chop any leading bits until we've got 32:

```
     00011101110101110110000000000000
```

And that value is 500654080.

Just use `long` instead, e.g.

```
long microDay = 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L * 1000L;
```

(You definitely don't need *all* those constants to be of type `long`, but being consistent means it's obvious that all the operations will be performed using 64-bit arithmetic, with no need to consider associativity etc.)

A better approach, however, would be to use [`TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html):

```
long microDay = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMicroseconds(1);
```

As for the division part, you're performing integer division - so the result is the integer part, rounded towards 0. If you want floating point arithmetic, you need to cast one of the operands to `float` or `double`... although if you start off with the right values, of course, you should get an exact integer anyway (1000).

Comment: can you explain why i got 500654080 and can you include in your answer why there is difference in result while dividing

Comment: @rocking: As I said, the calculation overflowed `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. You can't represent `86400000000` and an `int`, so the operation overflows. As for the division - you're using integer division, so you can't possibly get a floating point result..

Comment: I mean why 500654080  why not 500654090 or 500654060 or 500654070? why 500654080 ?How the calculation is made?

Answer (score 2):

For the first part, put a "L" at the end of one (or more) of the constants and Java will then use long arithmetic.  e.g.

```
long microDay = 24L * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000;
```

**Addendum**:  Why did you get 500654080?

86400000000 decimal = 141DD76000 hex.
But, the integer only holds 32 bits, which is 8 "digits".  So you lose the leading 14 and retain 1DD76000 hex.
Converting that to decimal gives 500654080.

As for the division, when you divide ints by ints (or longs by longs) Java returns the result as an int or long, so it has to truncate (or round, but Java chose to truncate) the result to 5 instead of 5.7946...   Force it to do floating point arithmetic by casting one of the values to a double, e.g.

```
System.out.println((double)microDay/ miliDay);
```

Comment: please explain why I got 500654080

Answer (score 0):

When you are performing a division between 2 integers, the results are an integer. The results of the arithmetic operation will be rounded down to the nearest integer.

```
int i = 5 / 2; // 2.5 is rounded down to 2
```

if you want the output to include the decimal precision, you will need to use a different primitive data type and explicitly specify your operands to be doubles.

```
double j = 5 / 2; //2.0 as 5 / 2 yields and integer 2 which will be casted to a double
double j = 5 / 2.0; //2.5 explicit usage of a double will tell the compiler to return the results in double
```

Answer (score 0):

The nuclear operations inside

```
long microDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000;
```

are all Integers specific. Max value of Integer object is 2147483647. Which exceeds the original output which is long.

Simply specifying long to variable doesn't mean all operations using [ * ] will be done using long instances. All operations done in assignment became sort of truncated.

Solution is to explicitly specify that all nuclear operations should happen over long instance and not int instances.

```
long microDay = 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L * 1000L;
```